# Increasing thread efficency

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the following code that will read the bytes of a file then construct 8 separate strings and once done the 8 strings will then be pieced together but when reading a 500mb file this code is taking more than 10 hours and then I give up running it.

Is there anyway in increasing the efficiency of this code so it can run faster?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class object1
    {
        public static Byte[] split1 = new Byte[18082460];
        public static Byte[] split2 = new Byte[18082460];
        public static Byte[] split3 = new Byte[18082460];
        public static Byte[] split4 = new Byte[18082460];
        public static Byte[] split5 = new Byte[18082460];
        public static Byte[] split6 = new Byte[18082460];
        public static Byte[] split7 = new Byte[18082460];
        public static Byte[] split8 = new Byte[18082452];

        public static String[] output = new String[8];

        public void run1()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < split1.Length; i++)
            {
                output[0] += "0x" + split1[i] + ", ";
                Program.amountDone[0] += 1;
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }
        public void run2()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < split2.Length; i++)
            {
                output[1] += "0x" + split2[i] + ", ";
                Program.amountDone[1] += 1;
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }
        public void run3()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < split3.Length; i++)
            {
                output[2] += "0x" + split3[i] + ", ";
                Program.amountDone[2] += 1;
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }
        public void run4()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < split4.Length; i++)
            {
                output[3] += "0x" + split4[i] + ", ";
                Program.amountDone[3] += 1;
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }
        public void run5()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < split5.Length; i++)
            {
                output[4] += "0x" + split5[i] + ", ";
                Program.amountDone[4] += 1;
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }
        public void run6()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < split6.Length; i++)
            {
                output[5] += "0x" + split6[i] + ", ";
                Program.amountDone[5] += 1;
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }
        public void run7()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < split7.Length; i++)
            {
                output[6] += "0x" + split7[i] + ", ";
                Program.amountDone[6] += 1;
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }
        public void run8()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < split8.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == split8.Length)
                {
                    output[7] += "0x" + split8[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    output[7] += "0x" + split8[i] + ", ";
                }
                Program.amountDone[7] += 1;
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }
    };
    class Program
    {
        public static int curPoint = 0;
        public static object1 obj = new object1();
        public static Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(obj.run1));
        public static Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(obj.run2));
        public static Thread thread3 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(obj.run3));
        public static Thread thread4 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(obj.run4));
        public static Thread thread5 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(obj.run5));
        public static Thread thread6 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(obj.run6));
        public static Thread thread7 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(obj.run7));
        public static Thread thread8 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(obj.run8));
        public static int[] amountDone = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Byte[] bytes = GetBytesFromFile(@"C:\Users\JLT\Desktop\320kbTest.rar");

            Array.Copy(bytes, 0, object1.split1, 0, 18082460);
            Array.Copy(bytes, 18082461, object1.split2, 0, 18082460);
            Array.Copy(bytes, 36164922, object1.split3, 0, 18082460);
            Array.Copy(bytes, 54247383, object1.split4, 0, 18082460);
            Array.Copy(bytes, 72329844, object1.split5, 0, 18082460);
            Array.Copy(bytes, 90412305, object1.split6, 0, 18082460);
            Array.Copy(bytes, 108494766, object1.split7, 0, 18082460);
            Array.Copy(bytes, 126577227, object1.split8, 0, 18082452);

            thread1.Start();
            thread2.Start();
            thread3.Start();
            thread4.Start();
            thread5.Start();
            thread6.Start();
            thread7.Start();
            thread8.Start();


            String output = "Byte[] rawData = { ";

            while (true)
            {
                if (thread1.IsAlive || thread2.IsAlive || thread3.IsAlive || thread4.IsAlive || thread5.IsAlive || thread6.IsAlive || thread7.IsAlive || thread8.IsAlive)
                {
                    int temp = 0;
                    foreach (int inter in amountDone)
                    {
                        temp += inter;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(temp + " | " + bytes.Length);
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    Console.Clear();
                }
                else
                {
                    int temp = 0;
                    foreach (int inter in amountDone)
                    {
                        temp += inter;
                    }
                    if (temp < bytes.Length - 1)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            output += object1.output[0];
            output += object1.output[1];
            output += object1.output[2];
            output += object1.output[3];
            output += object1.output[4];
            output += object1.output[5];
            output += object1.output[6];
            output += object1.output[7];

            output += "};";
            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }

        public static byte[] GetBytesFromFile(string fullFilePath)
        {
            FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fullFilePath);
            try
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Read(bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
                fs.Close();
                return bytes;
            }
            finally
            {
                fs.Close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Get rid off the Thread.Sleep, study StringBuilder, have a look at [waithandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.aspx) and several other bits...

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but my first thought would be to not load the entire file at once.  Load a section of it, process, load then next section, process, etc.  If you do it that way with a stream you can reduce the memory your program is using which might help.

Comment: And for goodness sake you don't need 8 run methods.  Just add a couple parameters and pass in what it should be working with.  Of course, if you take Jon's advice that will make it even easier.

Comment: @BrandonMoore I have seen how to send params to threads I just haven't implemented it yet because the base code needs to be working first.

Comment: You need to scrap this code and start fresh. Honestly when you first do some reading about concurrent code you will often be tempted to apply it unnecessarily. Open the file on one thread and and write to an output file. I wouldn't be surprised if the code runs in just a few minutes.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there anyway in increasing the efficiency of this code so it can run faster?

Well, I can see two immediate problems:

- You're sleeping in your loops. Why?
- You're using string concatenation a *huge* number of times. That's going to be *awful* when creating long strings.

Personally, I would recommend you get rid of the threading *completely* to start with. It's making the code *far* more complicated, and I suspect that when you've fixed the two problems above, you'll be fine with a single thread.

Given that you're just writing the output to the console, the simplest approach would be to avoid reading the whole file into memory at all. Just read a block at a time (e.g. 32K) and iterate over each byte, writing the hex value of each byte out to the console (which I would expect to be buffered...) directly.

If you *must* build the strings up in memory, use a `StringBuilder` - see [my article on the topic](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html) for a detailed explanation - but I really don't think you should do so at all.

Comment: That cupcake hat is so you. :)

Comment: I changed all the strings to StringBuilders it did run for about 15 seconds and got pretty far then crashed due to no memory left, would this be due to having an array of stringbuilders or just the stringbuilders being too long?

Comment: @JordanTrainor: Nope, it's due to you keeping too much string data in memory. I wouldn't be surprised to see your original code doing the same thing if you left it for long enough. Why have you gone straight for the solution I *didn't* recommend, instead of trying the far simpler solution I *did* recommend?

Comment: I did get rid of the sleeps and the final program wont just be outputting to the console the console output was just so I know the program has finished. I also got rid of all the thread and just left the main thread and one additional thread. same result

Comment: @JordanTrainor: Well where *would* you be writing to? Basically you've got 6 characters per byte (and that's assuming you fix it so it *actually* writes in hex, which it's not doing at the moment). Each character in .NET takes 2 bytes, so your app will need 12 times as much memory as the size of the file. That sounds like a *really* bad idea to me. Streaming it will be much more sensible.

Comment: @JonSkeet when its sending the hex data to the string its not supposed to be hex due to it being raw data that I need. Once I have the raw data it will be piped to another application on the network with a checksum

Answer (score 3):

Your program processes 144 MByte of data with 8 threads that process 1 byte and then go to sleep for 1ms.

Thus, your programm will spend at least 5 hours sleeping...

I propose you remove the `Thread.Sleep` and try if that increases the efficiency of your program.